# Get Fastest Time Difference on Order and Response in Two DataFrames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes as shown. The first (df1) has orders IDs, user IDS, and the time the user orders something.  In df2, I have the orderIds and the time the order was responded to (timeResponse).  What I need is a dataframe that takes these two dataframes and outputs each order ID, and if it was responded to, the time difference between the order time and the fastest order response.  Thus, in the first order (order ID 1), there were 3 responses, with the first one being at 2pm - so it would be a 2 hour response.

I'm looking for a way to do this in R.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
    orderID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    userID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105),
    timeOrdered = c("1/1/2020  12:00:00 PM", "1/2/20 1:00PM", "1/3/20 12:00 AM", "1/4/20  12:00 AM", "1/5/20 12:00 AM"))

df2 <- data.frame(responseID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    orderID = c(101, 102, 103, 104, 105),
    timeResponse = c("1/1/20 2:00 PM", "1/1/20 3:00 PM", "1/1/20 4:00 PM", "1/4/20 2:00 PM", "1/5/20 2:00 PM"))
```

Comment: See [the joins question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Thanks...actually, the second is. df2 <- data.frame(responseID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
    orderID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    timeResponse = c("1/1/20 2:00 PM", "1/1/20 3:00 PM", "1/1/20 4:00 PM", "1/4/20 2:00 PM", "1/5/20 2:00 PM"))

Comment: Yes. I fixed it in my comment. Anyway the join worked for me.

Comment: Great to hear - feel free to provide your own solution as an answer.

Comment: Here is how I answered it. 
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "orderID", all.x = TRUE) %>% mutate(diff=difftime(timeResponse,timeOrdered)) %>% select(orderID,diff) %>% group_by(orderID) %>% slice(which.min(diff))